# Qtcreator debugger not found (linux)

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, qt5

I have Qt 5.3.1 installed in my Linux (OpenSuse 13.1). 
When I try to launch any C++ project in QtCreator in debug mode, it says:

Debugger '{b2c1138f-47fe-4005-843e-d514ea660dd2}' not found.

Though, it works nicely when I launch it without debugging.

What is wrong? I have gdb installed and working.

Comment: Have a look there: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-engines.html and tell us if you are stuck.

Comment: I've clicked there "auto detect", and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @ashmanov, read [this article(click it).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615326/qtcreator-debugger-not-found-linux)

Comment: @ashmanov, I mean:
_Eventually you'll resolve the problem or find a work-around (which may be, "This won't work, so here's what I did instead"). Please add an answer with this information and accept your own answer so that others with your same question can see the path you eventually followed_.

Comment: Thank you, I've done it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've clicked there "auto detect", and now it works! Thank you!